When Importing a MP3 File To Unity It Outputs an Error
When Importing a MP3 File To Unity It Outputs An Error:
"Errors during import of AudioClip Assets/BooSound (1).mp3:
FSBTool ERROR: The format of the source file is invalid, see output for details.
FSBTool ERROR: Internal error from FMOD sub-system.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)"
I have it on the Vorbis compression format, and MP3 for Android (I'm making a VR Game)
I tried Changing the Compression Mode to everything and that's about it
If more info is needed please ask immediately.

According to another post, the solution they had was to simply reconvert the file into .mp3, but make sure the converter has ffmpeg.
If that doesn't work, here's a list of different unity supported audio file types - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html
Hope this helps :)

That was the Fix! I had been renaming my file to convert it to MP3 (which i thought worked) but it didn't. had to find a converter. Thanks!
